# Moved from ec2 to S3 static hosting breaks Chrome DNS resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, google-chrome

I migrated an old website to a static version of it. Everything was hosted on EC2 and the Route53 hosted zone was configured like this :

- `A` record for `exemple.com` pointing to ec2 instance IP
- `CNAME` record for `www.example.com` pointing to `example.com`

The site is not statically hosted on AWS S3 and the Route53 hosted zone was configured like this :

- `A` record for exemple.com pointing to `ALIAS s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.
- `A` record pointing `www.example.com` pointing to `ALIAS s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Everything works fine on every browser and any machine except on Chrome when the website has been previously visited with the old hosted zone configuration. It looks like Chrome is failing to resolve the correct DNS address. When I try to access the website, it loads forever. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I have difficulty distinguishing the old and new configurations; can you make it more explicit? You use "was" in both cases. Are you certain you have removed the CNAME (or the ALIAS)? I understand that a Firefox or other browser running on the same machine as the Chrome returns the correct site? What does the host resolution on the Chrome machine say? How long has it been since the change? (Also, it's "example" in English, not "exemple").

Comment: Have you cleared your browsing data in Chrome?

Comment: You can clear Chrome's DNS resolver by opening `chrome://net-internals/#dns`. Check if that helps.

Comment: I have cleared Chrome's DNS cache and browsing data.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had a permanent 300 redirect on the previous application. As a result the S3 hosting was not working as it's just HTTP and not HTTPS. I created a cloudfront distribution and added HTTPS support. It works now.